# Sequelize associate and query for this mysql query

Tags: mysql, node.js, orm, sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

I just want to excute this simple mysql query in sequelize but It's really confusing..

```
SELECT *,
       (SELECT COUNT(*)
         FROM  user_review_like
        WHERE  user_review_like.review_id = review.id)
FROM  reviews
```

so I tried like this.

```
const reviewList = await Review.findAndCountAll({
  attributes: ['*', fn('COUNT', col('user_review_like'))],
  include: [
    {
      model: UserReviewLike,
      attributes: [],
    },
  ],
  where,
  raw: true,
  offset: offset,
  limit: 5,
  order,
});
```

but It said 'userReviewLike is not associated to Review!'

Model 'review':

```
static associate(db) {
  db.Review.belongsTo(db.User); --> for matching review writer and users
  db.Review.belongsToMany(db.User, {through: 'user_review_like', foreignKey: 'review_id'});
}
```

Model 'user':

```
static associate(db) {
  db.User.hasMany(db.Review);
  db.User.belongsToMany(db.Review, {through: 'user_review_like', foreignKey: 'user_id'});
}
```

Model 'userReviewLike':

```
{
    user_id: {
    },
    review_id: {
    },
  },
static associate(db) {
db.UserReviewLike.belongsTo(db.User, {
  foreignKey: 'user_id'
});
db.UserReviewLike.belongsTo(db.Review, {
  foreignKey: 'review_id'
});
```

}

It seems much more convenient cuz I'm setting where and order dynamically,
but I'm confused about join query.

any advice please

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be able to indicate a junction model in `include` explicitly you also should define an association from `Review` to `UserReviewLike` explicitly:

```js
db.Review.hasMany(db.UserReviewLike, { foreignKey: 'review_id' })
```

And I suppose to be able to use `COUNT` as a subquery you need to use `Sequelize.literal`, otherwise you will get something like `SELECT *, COUNT(*) ...`

```js
const reviewList = await Review.findAndCountAll({
  attributes: { include: [
    [literal('(SELECT COUNT(*)
         FROM  user_review_like
        WHERE  user_review_like.review_id = review.id)'), 'like_count']
  ]
  },
  where,
  raw: true,
  offset: offset,
  limit: 5,
  order,
});
```